# Define new columns using values of a row in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, case

the below code works

```
SET @SQL = '  
SELECT SC.Name AS BUYER, 
CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''ANANTA'' THEN OM.OrderQty END AS Unit1_Qty
FROM LineAllocation LA
INNER JOIN OrderMaster OM ON LA.OrderRef= OM.OrderRefID
INNER JOIN AmanOTS..FileRef FR ON FR.FileRefID = OM.FileRefID
INNER JOIN SystemManager..Contacts SC ON SC.Code=OM.BuyerCode
INNER JOIN SystemManager..ProductionProcessCostCenter PPC ON PPC.CostCenter= LA.Line
'
Exec(@sql)
```

But I want another column as result of the case condition. I tried this,

```
CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''ANANTA'' THEN OM.OrderQty END AS Unit1_Qty,
Unit1_Qty * FR.Rate as Unit1_Value
```

and this

```
CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''ANANTA'' THEN OM.OrderQty END AS Unit1_Qty,
CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''ANANTA'' THEN Unit1_Qty * FR.Rate END AS Unit1_Value
```

But they dont work. What can I do now?

Comment: So if factory name is something other than 'Ananta', you don't want these columns at all?

Comment: You've forgotten the ELSE Statement:

Comment: @Rigel1121 You can use `CASE` without `ELSE`.

Comment: @ shree.pat18 Actualy i have 3 values in factory name column and i was planning 3 different case statement for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not refer to alias of result field in SELECT statement

```
SET @SQL = '  
SELECT SC.Name AS BUYER, 
CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''ANANTA'' THEN OM.OrderQty END AS Unit1_Qty,
-- OM.OrderQty instead of Unit1_Qty
CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''ANANTA'' THEN OM.OrderQty * FR.Rate END AS Unit1_Value 
FROM LineAllocation LA
INNER JOIN OrderMaster OM ON LA.OrderRef= OM.OrderRefID
INNER JOIN AmanOTS..FileRef FR ON FR.FileRefID = OM.FileRefID
INNER JOIN SystemManager..Contacts SC ON SC.Code=OM.BuyerCode
INNER JOIN SystemManager..ProductionProcessCostCenter PPC ON PPC.CostCenter= LA.Line
'
Exec(@sql)
```